# Using Duration.ofMillis with a nanoseconds value

Tags: java, guava, micrometer

I found a piece of code implementing timer for micrometer and I need help decoding the following code snippet because I think I'm understanding it incorrectly. As per my understanding, stopwatch.stop().elapsed(Nanos) will return nanoseconds it took from the time stopwatch was started till it was stopped.

Now for Duration.ofMillis, I read the Java docs and it says that a milliseconds value is supposed to be passed in here. This piece of code passes nanoseconds so in this case, will the duration.ofMillis part work? Assuming the stopwatch stopped after 100ms, I think Duration.ofMillis will get the value 100000000. I can't figure out after that what happens.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        meterRegistry.timer(name)
                .record(Duration.ofMillis(stopwatch.stop().elapsed(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)));
```

Comment: Why do you *think `Duration.ofMillis()` will get the value `100 000 000`*? And why don't you try it? Hint: There's also `Duration.ofNanos(long nanos)`.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you find this code snippet?
To me this seems wrong not just because the measurement seems wrong but because [Micrometer has such a mechanism](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_recording_blocks_of_code) and also because [measuring elapsed time is harder than one would think](https://develotters.com/posts/how-not-to-measure-elapsed-time/).

You can do this:

```java
Timer.Sample sample = Timer.start();
// do stuff
sample.stop(registry.timer(name));
```

or these:

```java
timer.record(() -> doSomething());
timer.recordCallable(() -> getSomething());
```

or pass an instrumented Runnable/Callable to an ExecutorService/CompletionService

```java
Runnable r = timer.wrap(() -> doSomething());
Callable c = timer.wrap(() -> getSomething());
```